# How to access the router in front of my networks router?

Tags: router, routing, routing-table

Okay, so here is a short description of the network in our house:

(1) FritzBox - connecting to the internet and also the rest of the house. It's located in the basement and uses the IP 192.168.178.1

(2) D-LINK Router running OpenWRT firmware - the hardware firewall between the Fritzbox and my private network router. It is shown in the Gateway information of Router (3) with the IP 192.168.1.1

(3) Synology - Router for my private network with IP Range 10.0.4.XX

The IP addres of all three routers is known and they have different IP ranges. All 3 have DHCP enabled, since at least (1) and (3) are serving their own networks.

Now my question: It is of course no problem to get to the web UI of the Synology router from a PC connected to it.

But how can I get to the web UI of the two other routers in front of it? If I simply type their IP I won't get any connection, so I guess I need to somehow tell the router where he should bring me. Guessing some (static) routes?

What do I need to setup on which router to be able to reach the UI's of the DLink and Fritzbox router from a PC connected to the Synology router?

Thanks a lot in advance and I hope I delivered enough information. And yes, I'm pretty new to this topic.

Comment: If all routers are performing NAT this shouldn’t be an issue. Please indicate if you are using NAT on router #2 and #3? If you are not using NAT than each router (1 and 2) need to have static routes for the networks behind router 2 and 3.

Comment: well, I just found the culprit and it's a bit ashaming. My VPN is accepting network IP's of my own network, but handles IP's outside like outgoing traffic. Disconnecting the VPN makes both routers accessible >< 
But thanks a lot for your answer, it made me research and finally find the issue!